# Want to display 4 images in a row, with a description below each image

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm tring to practice table-less design, and I trying to get the following:

**4 images per row**, and under each image is the name of the image.

So my DOM:

```
<div id="images">
     <div class="imageblock">
           <div class="image"><a href=""><img src=""/></a></div>
           <div class="meta">some filename</div>
     </div>
     <div class="imageblock">
           <div class="image"><a href=""><img src=""/></a></div>
           <div class="meta">some filename</div>
     </div>
      ..

</div>
```

Comment: You need help with your css I'm guessing?

Comment: Why is it not working (i.e. what are you expecting to happen, and what happens isntead)? And what CSS have you applied?

Comment: voting to close... stackoverflow is not the place for design questions. (see faq above)

Answer (score 3):

You're much better off using lists for this. Here's some code I've implemented for my daughters' site:

```
<ul id="galleries">
    <li>
        <a href="/gallery/image_full/6/"><img src="/img/gallery/May2010/with-daddy_thumb.jpg"  class="border" width="200" height="200" border="0" title="With Daddy and his beard" /></a>
        <p>With Daddy and his beard</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/gallery/image_full/8/"><img src="/img/gallery/May2010/with-mommy_thumb.jpg"  class="border" width="200" height="200" border="0" title="Mommy and Me" /></a>
        <p>Mommy and Me</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/gallery/image_full/7/"><img src="/imggallery/May2010/with-grandad_thumb.jpg"  class="border" width="200" height="200" border="0" title="With Grandad" /></a>
        <p>With Grandad</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/gallery/image_full/4/"><img src="/img/gallery/May2010/on-the-mat_thumb.jpg"  class="border" width="200" height="200" border="0" title="On the mat" /></a>
        <p>On the mat</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

css:

```
#galleries li
{
    width:225px;
    display:inline-block;
}
#galleries li p
{    
    margin:10px 0 20px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My Advice is :

Use UL and LI tags...

```
<ul class="gallery">
    <li>
        <a href="http://www.rbacarin.com.br/novo-ka-st-2009/17042010207.jpg" class="thumb"><span><img src="17042010207_t.jpg" alt="Who we are" /></span></a>
        <h2><a href="http://www.rbacarin.com.br/novo-ka-st-2009/17042010207.jpg">1</a></h2>

    </li>
...
</ul>
```

and this css:

```
ul.gallery {
    width: 708px;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 auto; padding: 0;
}
ul.gallery li {
    float: left;
    margin: 10px; padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px; /*--CSS3 Rounded Corners--*/
    -khtml-border-radius: 3px; /*--CSS3 Rounded Corners--*/
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px; /*--CSS3 Rounded Corners--*/
    display: inline; /*--Gimp Fix aka IE6 Fix--*/
}
```

as you can see in my site, look the source:
http://www.rbacarin.com.br/novo-ka-st-2009/salao-acessorios-2010-clube-do-novo-ka.html

Answer (score 0):

```
#images {
  width: 800px;
  float: left;
}

.imageblock {
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
}

  .imageblock .image {
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
  }

  .imageblock .meta {
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
  }
```

Untested, but its pretty simple so should work. You'll want to add padding or margin as you see fit to seperate them all out a little.